# Unable to install ADT plugin to eclipse Juno

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm unable to install ADT to my eclipse juno. I'm getting following the error

"Unable to connect to repository https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/content.xml
Unable to connect to repository https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/content.xml
Connection timed out: connect"

I've tried most of the things that were mentioned here and other places with  no luck.

My internal browser in eclipse works fine, so, its not a proxy issue.

I got the same error when I tried to manually install it. help

Comment: How about stripping `https` to `http`?

Comment: Have you tried deleting Eclipse Juno, reinstalling Eclipse Juno, then reinstalling ADT Plugin? (Forfeiting your customized plugins and workspace)

Comment: I haven't tried that, I've kept that as my last resort. Its not feasible right now to reinstall juno.

Answer (score 0):

Disable your firewall. Worked for me.

*instructions:*

*Control Panel => Security => Windows Firewall => Check the "Off" option*